# zsh/bash string to array not working using parentheses

Tags: bash, zsh

Do you know why the following is not converting string into array?

```
  STR="one two three"
  array=("$STR")

  echo "${array[@]}" # prints: one two three
  echo "len: ${#array[@]}" # prints: len: 1
```

Update to communicate with @user1934428:

This works one line at the time:

```
  STR="one two three"
  array=( ${(z)STR} )
  echo "${array[@]}"
```

But in script `sh script.sh myarray`:

```
#!/bin/zsh

myarray(){
  STR="one two three"
  array=( ${(z)STR} )
  echo "${array[@]}"
}

script.sh: line 5: ${(z)STR}: bad substitution
```

Comment: Use `read -ra array <<< "$STR"`

Comment: To answer your question, it did - it created an array of length 1.  Nothing with your syntax would cause a "split" of the string.  To do the split use the previous suggestion.  So equivalent to the first echo is `echo "${array[0]}"`.

Comment: In bash: Because of the quoting. In zsh: Like bash, but additionally because you did not explicitly request word splitting. Please don't ask about two different programming languages in one question. It is perfectly fine to post two different questions, even if the topic looks similar.

Comment: Thanks, I have made an update to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat "73276948.sh"
#!/bin/bash
STR="one two three"
array=($STR)
echo "${array[@]}"              # prints: one two three
echo "len:      ${#array[@]}"   # prints: len: 1
echo "1ST:      ${array[0]}"            # prints: one two three
echo "2ND:      ${array[1]}"            # prints: one two three
echo "3RD:      ${array[2]}"            # prints: one two three
echo "Using loop:"
for (( indx = 0; indx < ${#array[@]}; indx++ ))
do
        echo "$indx" "${array[indx]}"
done
```

Output:

```
$ ./73276948.sh
one two three
len:    3
1ST:    one
2ND:    two
3RD:    three
Using loop:
0 one
1 two
2 three
```

Related difference:

```
array=("$STR")
```

```
array=($STR)
```

Comment: Your answer would be correct in bash, but the OP now has tagged the question zsh. It is unfortunate that the OP changed this later on, making your answer invalid.

Comment: Actually, from what I see, the OP changed the tag between bash and zsh forth and back. This is really confusing.

Answer (score 4):

You have to tell **zsh** that you want word splitting to occur:

```
array=( ${(z)STR} )
```

**NOTE** This applies to *zsh*. At the time I was writing the answer, the question was tagged *zsh*, but meanwhile the tag was changed to *bash*. In **bash**, the assignment would be

```
array=( $STR )
```

**UPDATE** (for bash): As Gordon Davisson points out in his comment, this assignment would work in bash for the concrete example posted here, but would not work if `STR` contains glob characters. So, for bash,

```
read -ra array <<< "$STR"
```

would be a better choice.

Comment: I found this to be working better eval "array=($STR)" as I got  ${(z)STR}: bad substitution. I will keep this

Comment: Don't do eval unless you have to!!! If someone sneaks in code, it will get execution. The use of `(z)` certainly works; I tried it out. What do you get when you do a `echo $ZSH_VERSION`? Maybe you are using a very old version of zsh.

Comment: I have version 5.8.1

Comment: I see that it is after 5.0  https://zsh.sourceforge.io/releases.html

Comment: Warning: in bash, an unquoted variable expansion (like `array=( $STR )`) will not only word-split the variable, but also try to expand anything that looks like a wildcard into a list of matching filenames. This can lead to completely silly results, so I'd use @anubhava's suggestion of `read -ra array <<< "$STR"` instead.

Comment: Good point! I will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: @ChrisG.: I'm using 5.8, so this **should** work in your zsh as well. Can you try it on the command line and post a screenshot, so I can see the exact statement you are using and the error message?

Comment: array=( ${(z)"one two three"} )
zsh: bad substitution

Comment: @ChrisG: The literal string _one two three_ does not make sense. It is obvious that you will get an error message for this. Type the command exactly as I wrote in my answer. And show a link to a screenshot.

Comment: `zsh` allows an extension to the POSIX `$(name:-value}` syntax, where `name` is optional. This lets you define "anonymous" variables on which the various expansion flags can be applied. `array=( ${(z):-"one two three"} )` (Though in this case, you would just write `array=(one two three)` anyway.)

Comment: @chepner: Good to know, and it also explains, why the OP got that error message. I could verify that this works, but I now I would be curious to know a concrete use case for this feature.

Comment: The default value itself can be a more complicated expression, not just literal text.